# Check property exists to stop error; cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty

Tags: json, vb.net, linq, json.net

JSON:

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "maximum_reached": 0,
  "top_domain": {
    "dont_show": 1
  },
  "free_domains": [
    {
      "status": "AVAILABLE",
      "domain": "go",
      "tld": ".tk",
      "currency": "USD",
      "type": "SPECIAL",
      "price_int": "1000",
      "price_cent": "00",
      "show_top_domain": 0,
      "is_in_cart": 0
    },
  ]
}
```

VB.NET code:

```
Dim jsonObj As JObject = JObject.Parse(hr.Html)

If IsNothing(jsonObj.[Property]("free_domains")(0)("status")) Then

End If
```

Error:

> Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty

How can I check the property exists to make sure not to trigger the error when it's not available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property named `free_domains` does exist in your `jsonObj` and if you check the return value of `jsonObj.[Property]("free_domains")`, it does contain an appropriate object.

The point is that `jsonObj.[Property]("free_domains")` returns an object of type `JProperty`, which is a property descriptor. This descriptor does not represent the property value directly. In order to access this value, use `JProperty.Value`:

```
jsonObj.[Property]("free_domains").Value(0)("status")
```

There is an easier way to access the value, though. Use the string indexer of the `jsonObj`:

```
jsonObj("free_domains")(0)("status")
```

To check if a property exists, check if the value returned by the string indexer is not `Nothing`. Null-conditional operator may prove handy when accessing a series of properites in a hierarchy:

```
If IsNothing(jsonObj("free_domains")?(0)?("status")) Then

End If
```

Comment: Your answer has helped me for  a similar problem.